# Adding a warning to `date -s` calls

Tags: linux, date

I'm prone to calling `date -s` instead of `date -d`, and this can go badly when I call it on the wrong server. Is there a way to add a confirmation prompt to `date -s` so I realize what I've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help but state the obvious, that you should be more careful when typing commands...
Nevertheless, I would suggest the following as a workaround.

Write a script , that checks the CLI arguments passed to the `date` command, let's call it `/bin/date.sh` (example below) and change its permission to `755`:

```
chmod 755 /bin/date.sh
cat /bin/date.sh

#!/bin/bash

### script to prompt at 'date -s'

if [[ $1 == -s* ]]; then
    read -p "*** Are you sure you want to set the date ? [y/n]" ANS
    if [[ $ANS = [Yy] ]]; then
        /bin/date $1
    fi
else
    /bin/date $1
fi
```

Make an alias in your user's `.bashrc` file to that script instead like `alias date=/bin/date.sh`. This way, every time you call `date` that script is run and it lets you know you issued the set date command flag and asks for confirmation.

You may also avoid using an alias, by simply replacing the `date` command, like below, but please also change the date binary's name in the script from `/bin/date` to `/bin/date_cmd`

mv /bin/date /bin/date_cmd
mv /bin/date.sh /bin/date

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I'll see about getting this implemented. I would definitely prefer to check my commands before putting them through, but sometimes there's an intersection of 3 AM and Linux.